# Object expected error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

The code works as it should in Firefox and Chrome.

When the page loads in Internet Explorer, you get the error

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; eSobiSubscriber 2.0.4.16; FDM; InfoPath.3)
> Timestamp: Wed, 18 Aug 2010 13:48:54 UTC

and when you press a link

```
<a href="javascript:toggleLayer('sub< ? echo $l; ?>');"><? echo $alp[$l]; ?></a>
```

you get the error

> Message: Object expected
> Line: 4
> Char: 1
> Code: 0
> URI:
>
> Message: Object required
> Line: 24
> Char: 4
> Code: 0
> URI:

There are no errors in Firefox or Chrome, just IE.

Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
function toggleLayer( whichLayer )
{
  var sub=new Array();
  for (i=1;i<25;i++)
  {
  sub[i] = 'sub'+i;
 }
  var elem, vis;
  if( document.getElementById ) // this is the way the standards work
    elem = document.getElementById( whichLayer );
  else if( document.all ) // this is the way old msie versions work
      elem = document.all[whichLayer];
  else if( document.layers ) // this is the way nn4 works
    elem = document.layers[whichLayer];
  vis = elem.style;
  // if the style.display value is blank we try to figure it out here
  

  
  for (i=1;i<26;i++)
 {
   eelem = document.getElementById( sub[i] );
   vvis = eelem.style;
   if(eelem==elem){
    vvis.display = "block";
    } else {
    vvis.display = "none";
    }
 }
 
  if(vis.display==''&&elem.offsetWidth!=undefined&&elem.offsetHeight!=undefined)
    vis.display = (elem.offsetWidth!=0&&elem.offsetHeight!=0)?'block':'none';
  vis.display = (vis.display==''||vis.display=='block')?'none':'block';
}
```

Comment: The error your are having is related to your Javascript, not your PHP. I will retag your question.

Comment: Oh no, another instance of `if (document.all)`; you're still supporting *very* old browsers like IE 4 and NN 4?

Answer (score 5):

### The Problem

The "Object expected"/"Object required" error message in Internet Explorer is rather vague, but it's usually triggered when you are trying to access an attribute of an element which is undefined.

In your case, the undefined element you are probably trying to access is most probably located here :

```
for (i=1;i<26;i++)
 {
   eelem = document.getElementById( sub[i] ); // <---- UNDEFINED
   vvis = eelem.style; // <----- ERROR
   if(eelem==elem){
    vvis.display = "block";
    } else {
    vvis.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

The element "eelem" is undefined on the last iteration of the array, because you have previously only initialized the array "sub" with the index **1 to 24**. In the last iteration your are trying to access the index **25**. So in the last iteration here's what happen :

```
eelem = document.getElementById( sub[i] );
```

Is the same as

```
eelem = document.getElementById( undefined );
```

Which return undefined to eelem. The error is triggered when you are accessing an attribute of the variable eelem, because undefined does not have attribute.

### The Solution

To prevent this from happening you should either initialize the array with the index 1 to 25 or in your second loop, only loop the element 1 to 24.

Comment: Beat me to it, but I think the essence of the solution is that your first loop's condition is `i < 25`, while the second, it's `i < 26`. Make them both 25, and you'll be good.

Comment: Couple other suggestions... Don't bother looping twice (skip the array of IDs entirely) and do check the return value of `getElementById()` before trying to use it...

Comment: There's also an error in this line: `toggleLayer('sub< ? echo $l; ?>')`. If I'm not mistaken, you have to use `<?` without a space inbetween (or better: don't use short tags, but `<?php`).