# Object expected error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I asked this yesterday but could not reply as i was not registered , I tried out the suggestions that  HoLyVieR,Ryan Kinal  and Vagabond said, but non of them seem to work.

I have taken out the array as that seem to be the suggested problem and solution but now the code does not work at all but shows no error's.

The original question is here [Object expected error in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512817/object-expected-error-in-internet-explorer)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggleLayer( whichLayer )
{
  var elem, vis,eelem, vvis;

  if( document.getElementById ) // this is the way the standards work
    elem = document.getElementById( whichLayer );
  else if( document.all ) // this is the way old msie versions work
      elem = document.all[whichLayer];
  else if( document.layers ) // this is the way nn4 works
    elem = document.layers[whichLayer];
  vis = elem.style;


for (i=0;i<25;i++)
{
    eelem = document.getElementById( 'sub'+i );
    vvis = eelem.style;
    if(eelem==elem){
        vvis.display = "block";
    } else {
        vvis.display = "none";
    }
}

  if(vis.display==''&&elem.offsetWidth!=undefined&&elem.offsetHeight!=undefined)
    vis.display = (elem.offsetWidth!=0&&elem.offsetHeight!=0)?'block':'none';
  vis.display = (vis.display==''||vis.display=='block')?'none':'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: How does this differ from your original question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object expected error in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512817/object-expected-error-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: I propose you mail to the SO people (see 'Contact Us' link below) and ask to merge your accounts, including their numbers. Add something like "Merge me with ..." to your description box, so they can see it's really you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error if anything from `sub0`, `sub1`, ... `sub24` doesn't exist. Are your elements perhaps named `sub1` - `sub25`, so that `document.getelementById('sub0');` doesn't find anything?

Your first section of code checks if `document.getElementById` exist, and if not, it falls back on `document.all` or `document.layers`. In the block of code immediately after that, you assume that `document.getElementById` exists. You should be consistent in your assumptions, whichever way you decide to go.