# Angular 8 not working in IE11 even with polyfills

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular 8 project and have included the core-js poly fills in my polyfills.ts file.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

When I load the app up in IE11, I get an error that says
 Object expected at tick in vendor-es5.js on line 130k

I started commenting out my code and noticed it was breaking when I used a `for...of` loop. If I change the loop to something like a `.forEach` the issue goes away. Problem is I have a ton of `for...of` loops throughout my code and I like the fact I can break out of the loop using a `return`

Any ideas? Been trying to figure this out since Friday. I’m sure I can change all my code to use forEach, but I feel like I’m missing something simple.

EDIT: Added how I am initializing the object.

```
mcgs = {};

constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private router: Router, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.configService.getMcgData().subscribe((response) => {
    this.mcgs = response; <-- might be an issue.
    ......
```

Comment: have you followed all of the directions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455 you shuold be fine to use for of... transpiling can handle it

Comment: You are right..for..of does work. I nailed the issue to being associated with [ngClass] of all things. After lots of console logs, this does not work in IE11 `<ul [ngClass]="{'hidden-loc': activeLoc}">` That is what throws the error, `Object expected`. Instead I did `<ul [ngClass]="(activeLoc) ? 'hidden-loc' : ''">` and all is good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support `for-of` or anything else in ES2015+ (except for some slightly incorrect support for `let` and `const`).

If you want your project to run in IE11, you need not to use `for-of`, or to transpile your code to ES5 with a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io).

Comment: I was under the impression the polyfills took care of adding support for things like for..of. Is that not the case with angular?

Comment: @Ronnie - Polyfills can't address *syntax*, just library methods that were added. For instance, you can polyfill the `Object.fromEntries` method (to pick a random example). You can't polyfill `for-of` or shorthand property syntax or destructuring or... To deal with modern syntax in obsolete environments, you need to transpile.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I don’t know why I thought when I run ‘ng build’ it does the transpiling to make it work in IE. I will look onto Babel if I am not going to change all the for..of loops

Comment: @Ronnie - It'll depend on what your build is doing (it may be transpiling already), and what target output you've set for it (maybe it's set to just target ES2015 rather than ES5). :-) Happy coding!

Comment: My tsconfig target is indeed set to es2015

Comment: Changing my tsconfig target to es5 and updating my browserlist file to include IE11, it still doesn't work. Should it be working or is there absolutely no way using for..of will work in IE11 after its transpiled?

Comment: ..I am stumped man, I changed all my `for..of` loops to plain ole `for` loops and I am getting the same error. In this screen shot (https://i.imgur.com/uAtUJOu.png) is my console logged object (specifically the carriers, guidelines, loc and uc properties). Immediately after I `console.log(this.mcgs)` the error below is displayed. I am getting this data from an API that is a rather large JSON string. Any ideas? I am still including the core-js polyfills and my browserlist still includes `IE 11`

Comment: I am thinking this might have something to do with how I am initializing my this.mcgs object. I posted it in my OP. I found this answer and could possibly be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512977/736967

Comment: just to update, for...of does work as angular is apparently transpiling. See the comment on my OP for what the issue ended up being. I still dont understand how that was causing the issue. It is a completely valid way of using ngclass